# System DateTime Format is changed

Tags: c#, windows-7, datetime-format

I have Window 7 installed in my computer. The problem is that the system date format is changed some time if computer is restarted. I need to make the date format fixed but don't know how. I have application built in mvc 3 and have code for **string to datetime** conversion. If system datetime format doesn't match with string it show error that 
`string is not in proper format` for converting into datetime which looks for system datetime. The exception is thrown in following code:

```
 DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
```

where,

```
string start = sundayOfLastWeek.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Or, Is there any alternatives so that I can change in code that works all the time despite the system Date Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) for values persistance. Only omit CultureInfo if you render values for display purpose. For some specific data formats special formatting rules may exist - follow them.

to recover your data use ParseExact.

Answer (score 4):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the format `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

```
startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, 
                                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT: based on comment from @John Woo

You can pass string array to DateTime.Parse like:

```
string[] dateFormats = new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "d/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start,
                                         dateFormats, 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                         DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: sir, what if the datetime is not in the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`? what will happen?

Comment: It will throw an exception, to avoid that you can add possible/expected datetime formats in the string array and pass that to the method

Comment: it shows error saying that ParseExact: no overload for method that have two argument.

Comment: It has three arguments, the last one is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

As Habib already answered:

```
//Add any format you want or expect
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start, formats,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

It should help.